# Summarise to largest category

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, forcats

I have an issue I face sometimes. I want to collapse my data frame and one column should return the largest category within the group, even if there are multiple observations for each category. Example:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
             cat = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "D", "C", "C"),
             val = c(1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 8, 2, 1))

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# grp cat     val
# <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 A         1
# 2     1 B         2
# 3     1 B         1
# 4     1 A         4
# 5     2 C         1
# 6     2 D         8
# 7     2 C         2
# 8     2 C         1
```

**Expected output:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
    grp val biggest_cat
  <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>      
1     1        8 A          
2     2       12 D
```

Note that for group 2 i want cat D to be returned since the sum of val for D is larger than the sum for cat C.

**This works:**

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp, cat) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(val)) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(val),
           biggest_cat = first(cat, order_by = -val))
```

**But I want to do it without the double summarise:**

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(val),
           biggest_cat = <Some function>)
```

Maybe there is a forcats solution or something?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `group_by` `cat`, `grp` to calculate `sum` and select row with `max` value of `sum` in each `grp`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp, cat) %>% 
  summarise(val = sum(val)) %>%
  summarise(cat = cat[which.max(val)],
            biggest_cat = sum(val))
```

---

To do it with using one `summarise` we can use `tapply` :

```
df %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise(total_val = sum(val), 
            biggest_cat = names(which.max(tapply(val, cat, sum))))


#    grp total_val biggest_cat
#  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>      
#1     1         8 A          
#2     2        12 D
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for `cat` but the `sum` is incorrect. Your solution returns the sum of cat D rather than the sum for grp 2

Comment: @davsjob Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. That works great, but its close to my working solution that also uses summarise twice. I would like to remove that. However, it might not be possible :)